# how constructors work in java

Tags: java

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the following constructors in java in class

```
Box
{
    Box(Box ob)
    {
     width = ob.width;
     height = ob.height;
     depth = ob.depth;
    }

    Box(double w, double h, double d)
    {
     width = w;
     height = h;
     depth = d;
    }

    Box()
    {
     width = 0;
     height = 0;
     depth = 0;

    }

    Box(double width, double height, double depth)
    {
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.depth = depth;
    }
}
```

Cheers everyone

Comment: They take different parameters? Number 2 and 4 seem to be redundant, by the way.

Comment: Your 2nd and 4th one are syntactically the same.

Comment: The 2nd and 4th constructors are the same (same signature, `Box(double, double, double)`). But what do you really want to know?

Comment: is there any difference if you are using the first, third or the last one ?

Comment: First constructor is a copy constructor, as in it expects another `Box` object and will copy its `width`, `height`, `depth` properties from the passed-in `Box`. Third one is considered a default constructor, in that it takes no arguments. In this case it also initializes the fields to 0 each. The last one, you pass in the width/height/depth to make the Box have those values.

Comment: No, is the same, you have different ways to instantiate the object, but them all returns a Box

Comment: so there is no difference between using the first second the the last one? is that correct

Comment: 1st, 2nd/4th, and 3rd differ in the arguments they take and what they do to construct a `Box`. They can all be used to create `Box`, but they will do different things to initialize/set the values of the `Box`.

Comment: You can use my edit of the question. It will make the question more clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First is the copy constructor which is used to copy the values of one object to another during initialization.

Second and Fourth is a parametrized constructor which contains all the data members of the class. But it is recomended to use the fourth and most of the IDE(all that I know) will auto generate the 4th as it is easier to read and has the same context

Third is a default constructor. Used to set default values. See it does not take any inputs(as parameter)

```
Box b = new Box();//Default constructor
Box b1 = new Box(1.0,2.0,3.0);//Parameterized constructor completely defining the object
Box b2 = new Box(b1);//Copy constructor will copy the values but both will have a different reference
b2 = b1;//b2 now refers to object referenced by b1. So the earlier reference for b2 will be taken by GC(garbage Collector)
```

Comment: if we say b1 = b2 are we going to assign the reference of b2 to b1 and   to point to the same reference ?

Comment: yes. Hope my edit clarifies further

Comment: They point to the same object.

Comment: @dragon66 Out of the topic but I have stopped the usage of point(or **pointer**) ever since I moved on from C/C++ to Java :)

Answer (score 3):

The first one is often called a copy-contructor, which means you are copying values from an existing instance into the new one.  The 2nd and 4th (which are the same), are creating a new instance, initializing each field from explicit primitive values.  The third one appears to be an attempt at creating an instance with default values for fields, when you don't want to have to supply any explicitly.

Btw, the trivial difference between 2nd and 4th is that in the 2nd you are using different names for the parameters than the field names, so you don't have to say `"this.fieldname"` on the lefthand side.  In the 4th one, the parameters have the same names as the field names, and so you have to use `"this,fieldname"` on lefthand side to indicate that you are copying from the parameter to the field, rather than vice-versa (or from the parameter to itself, or from the field to itself).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am starting with an assumption that you did not write the `class` keyword with Box, and also omitted width, height and depth declarations just to save typing.

In Java, if you do not give any constructor, a default constructor is there by default that does not take any parameters. So if you did not write anything in class Box like below you would still be able to call its basic constructor in main:

```
class Box{
}

class CallingClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Box box = new Box(); // this would work.
    }
}
```

If you provide even one other constructor, then the undeclared default constructor is not available anymore until you declare it explicitly.

```
class Box{
    public Double height;

    public Box(Double height){
        this.height = height;
    }
}

class CallingClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Box box = new Box((double)50); // this would work.
        Box anotherBox = new Box(); // this will give you an error.
    }
}
```

Quickly over construtors:

```
public Box(){...} // default constructor in which you allow caller to not worry about initialization.

public Box(Box boxToCopy){...} // copy constructor for creating a new box from the values of an old one.

public Box(double height, double width, double depth){...} // should create a box with specified dimensions.
```